# Pushing visitor data from DialogFlow to ZohoCRM

Tags: dialogflow-es, crm, zoho

So I have connected DialogFlow to Zobot (Zoho Chatbot) and want to push information from DF to ZohoCRM.
My chatbot could sign someone up to a newsletter and once the person gives me their email I want to save that email and name in the ZohoCRM.

From what I can gather I have to use the DF webhooks to send information anywhere, I have found a sample code that can push data to the ZohoCRM but I want to customise it.

**My main questions**:

- If I have a user email that is stored in DF as @sys.email how do I refer to this value in my web-hook code?
- How do I specify what table and column the information must be stored in?
- Where do I set my Zoho CRM ZSC Key?

This is code taken from the Zobot integration documentation page (https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/schedule-a-call-and-push-visitor-data-to-zoho-crm-with-zobot-26-11-2018):

```
info crmdata; 
if(!crmdata.isEmpty())  
{ // update existing 
  _crmdata = crmdata.get(0);   
  info _crmdata;  
  leadid = _crmdata.get("id");  
  crmdata = zoho.crm.update("Leads",leadid,{"Full_Name":name},Map(),"your CRM connection name");  
}  
else 
{ 
  // create new lead 
  crmdata = zoho.crm.create("Leads",{"Email":email,"Full_Name":name},Map(),"your CRM connection name");  
} 
leadid = crmdata.get("id");  
info leadid;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If I have a user email that is stored in DF as @sys.email how do I refer to this value in my web-hook code?

When user will be added to zoho crm you can start with workflow rule function which will be adding the variable you want to.

2. How do I specify what table and column the information must be stored in?

You can not specify table or column where the information must be stored in. You can only add new one user. I've tried it many times, sorry ;/